# Edit Data is not coming selected with Ui component grid

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.2

We have created one grid with UI component for our custom module.

Add New, Delete and Mass delete functionality is working fine.

I have also added Edit data functionality.

I can get the data while I am doing **print_r** which I want to edit but it will not come as selected in UI form.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Show your data provider file

Comment: @Priyank Please check the link for data provider file 

https://prnt.sc/kj6ldk

Comment: I have resolved an issue

There is an issue with Data provider file into that there is a getData function which is empty. I have written code for same. and it's working fine.

Comment: Grt. You got it resolved